# Creating a user-tailored newsletter

Tags: database, parsing, newsletter

So I want to have a system that automatically sends out newsletters to my users that pretty much gives them a summary of their content interaction (ei. what they liked on my site, what they posted on their feed, etc.) and/or give them recommendations.

So essentially, I would like to pull from our database the users interaction and put it in a weekly template newsletter (something very similar to what pinterest does in their newsletters). I'm not super technical, but if their is service out there that will do that, would be great to know. Alternatively, if it's a better idea to have an in-house solution, bullet points would give a sufficient understanding. Thanks so much (ps. we are using parse:)

Answer (score 0):

There are many email service providers that have dynamic content and API's. You would connect via the API and you could then push the correct dynamic info the user-tailored newsletter. This is about as plug-and-play as it gets.

Unfortunately there is not a solution (that I'm aware of) that can do this level of customization without programming at least into an API.